# Subtract two columns with windows function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

How can i subtract two columns:

I have table:

```
      ID      COL 1      COL 2
     -------------------------
       1      200.00     70.00
       2      200.00     30.00
       3      200.00     90.00
       4      200.00    110.00
```

Col1 - COL2 but to continue for each row and value is reduced by the previously value

My output to be like as:

```
      ID      COL 1      COL 2     [COL3 AS RESULT]
     -------------------------
       1      200.00     70.00          130 
       2      200.00     30.00          100
       3      200.00     90.00           10
       4      200.00    110.00         -100
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want to subtract the cumulative amount of col2 from col1:

```
select id, col1, col2,
       (col1 - sum(col2) over (order by id)) as col3
from t;
```

Comment: this will not give the desired output. this will give the column values 130 , 170, 110, 90 for col3

Comment: @sam . . . Here is a SQL Fiddle demonstrating the answer:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/98b3e.

Answer (score 0):

You need recursive CTE to get running totals -

```
with cte as
(
select id,col1,col2,cast(col1 - col2 as decimal(5,2)) as val
from #a
where id = 1
union all
select b.id,b.col1,b.col2,cast(a.val - b.col2 as decimal(5,2))
from cte as a
inner join #a as b
on b.id = a.id + 1
)select * from cte
```